# How do you set up the crossdomain.xml for site whose URL is the machine name?

Tags: iis, jboss, cross-domain

I'm working on a Silverlight app hosted on IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003), which talks to a web service on a JBoss app server (JBoss 4.2.2 also on Windows Server 2003). The Silverlight app is only used on the LAN, so it's addressed with a URL like so: `http://machinename:88/`

I created a crossdomain.xml file for the JBoss server (as required by Silverlight) in `...\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\ROOT.war` with the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="machinename"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="machinename" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I get errors from Silverlight until I replace `"machinename"` with `"*"`. I also tried `"machinename:88"` with the same results as without the port. How are you supposed to specify the domain, when the URL is just the machine name and a port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting the domain to be fully qualified. Since your machinename is not a fully qualified domain name, it's failing on the check, and won't work unless you use something like machinename.local to access the site.

Your only solution in this scenario is to use `"*"`. I'm guessing that won't be an issue anyway, because you're probably only working on a secure internal network with such a machine name.

Comment: Okay, I had a feeling that might be the only solution, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks.